# Combining Simple, Near-Identical Select Statements

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

One of the parameters my PHP page accepts is a user-search query. The application then takes that query and performs >100 separate SELECT statements that look exactly like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE user = 'query';
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE user = 'query';
SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE user = 'query';
SELECT * FROM table4 WHERE user = 'query';
...etc...
```

Is there a faster/more efficient way to do what I'm trying to do? E.g. by combining all of the select statements into one statement somehow? I feel like having 100 individual queries going to my database would be slower than one large query. I do not know how to combine them though, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `union all` operator to combine these queries:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE user = 'query'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE user = 'query'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE user = 'query'
-- Etc...
```

That being said, you may want to reconsider your database design. If you always query these tables together, perhaps all the data should be added to one table.

Comment: Yes.. The main problem OP said he have `performs >100 separate SELECT statements`.. Better design database rather than do this..

Comment: You can also use the [MERGE Storage Engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/merge-storage-engine.html) to make multiple tables appear to be one table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Merge Storage Engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/merge-storage-engine.html) to create a virtual table that combines all those tables, and then query that table.

```
CREATE TABLE table1_100 (
    <column specifications>
) ENGINE=MERGE UNION=(table1, table2, table3, ...)
```

Then you can just write:

```
SELECT * FROM table1_100 WHERE user = 'query';
```

Comment: Will this work with very large tables though? My database is a little over 360GB and has ~5 billion rows. EDIT: Just read the documentation and learned that this won't work with tables that have different columns and whatnot. Thanks though

Comment: We use it for our transaction tables. We have a table for each year, and a merge table to allow searching all of them. Just make sure that the tables are properly indexed.

Comment: I assumed that your tables all had the same structure, since otherwise it doesn't really make sense to use `SELECT *` and return all the values from them.